# iPhone - NSDictionary - NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, key-value

I am grabbing a JSON output into a NSDictionary, the JSON output looks somewhat like this -

```
{"1":[{"abc":11},{"abc":13}]}
```

I was successful in grabbing they value for the first key *1* using the following:

```
NSDictionary *getData = [JSONOutput objectForKey:@"1"];
```

**Problem-** Now, I want to grab they values for keys "abc" and throw it into a MutableArray. I am using this for grabbing the values for key abc but it doesn't seem to be working

```
int count = 0;
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in getdata)
{
 [array addObject:[getdata objectForKey:@"abc"] atIndex:count];
count ++;
}
```

**Note:** JSONOutput is another dictionary where the JSON output is going in. I am allocating and initializing the dictionaries too.

Please help! I know its a really simple one but I have no clue where I am going wrong at..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element for key "1" is an array, not a dictionary (note the square bracket and the elements separated by a comma). The elements in the array are dictionaries. So:

```
NSArray *getData = [JSONOutput objectForKey:@"1"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in getdata)
{
    [array addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"abc"]];
}
```

Also, you don't need to use the `count` argument for `addObject:` if you are adding objects sequentially from zero.

Comment: Thanks a ton Evan. Wow! Works like a champ. :D :D